# Using DOH to unit test a non-Dojo javascript project

Tags: javascript, doh

Essentially I need help understanding this blog post:

http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/04/15/unit-testing-custom-code-with-the-dojo-objective-harness/

I want to use DOH to unit test an existing javascript project and I do not want to restructure that project to look like a Dojo widget.  My project is structured like so:

```
project/
   scripts/
      doh/
         ...
      tests/
         testA.js
      project.js
   tests/
      tests.html
   index.html
```

tests.html is a page with a single link to:

```
../scripts/doh/runner.html?testModule=scripts.tests.testA
```

testA.js does not appear to be loading, and I'm not sure what code should go in it so that it loads correctly as a test suite and also has access to the classes defined in project.js.

Answer (score 2):

Does your browser give any indication in its debugger tools as to whether it tried to load something called testA.js, and if so, where from?

If you have a path issue (it may be looking for 'scripts' as a sibling directory to your dojo directory), you can give DOH a hint in the runner URL as to how to map packages, e.g. `&registerModulePath=scripts,../../scripts` (this maps 'scripts' to '../../scripts'; you'll need to tweak that as appropriate as I can't see where your Dojo directory is)

Typically, you point 'testModule' at a module file, which is a file which simply pulls in test fixtures, but I think you can get away with just pointing at a test fixture file itself.  That just needs to call doh.register with some tests, and doh.run() to kick it all off.